# Dedekind Cut Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I finished reading the construction of $\mathbf R$ by Dedekind’s cuts from Rudin’s text. While I understand that now we can use the fact that $\mathbf R$ is an ordered field with the least upper bound property, and that multiplication, addition and the distributive properties hold in $\mathbf R$, I still feel like the construction leaves out what the elements of $\mathbf R$ actually are. For instance we know that $\sqrt 2$ is a real number. But it’s not obvious from the construction. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $\sqrt{2}\in \Bbb{R}$ with Dedekind cuts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913081/how-to-prove-sqrt2-in-bbbr-with-dedekind-cuts)

Comment: Yes thank you!!

Comment: Prove that the set $\{ q^2 < 2 : q \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ is a cut.

Comment: Once you have an ordered field with the least upper bound you can prove that $\alpha=\sup\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x^2 < 2\}$ is precisely $\sqrt{2}$, without using Dedekind cuts. I mean, you can prove that $\alpha^2=2$.

Comment: I recently created some pictures to help myself see what the elements of the real system actually are. Perhaps you'll like them: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4123656/688046

Comment: Thank you so much! Really a great illustration.